# Matrix Transpose and scalar

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some problems understanding the answer in my book for this question:

Let $A$ be any matrix and $k$ be a scalar. Prove that $(kA)^T=kA^T$

Books answer:
"Since k is a scalar (a $1\times 1$ matrix) we have $k^T = k$
therefore $(kA)^T=A^Tk^T=A^Tk=kA^T$"

Now, I understand the proof but I don't think it is valid, here are my reservations:

1. How can you view $k$ as a scalar and a matrix at the same time? The operation $kA$ shouldn't even be valid if $k$ is a matrix if $A$ has more than 1 column right?
2. And if you can't view $k$ as a matrix then $k^T$ is not defined since the author only has defined the transpose for matrices.
3. The author has only defined scalar multiplication for a scalar $k$ and a matrix $A$ as $kA$ and not $Ak$. Doesn't he have to make this definition before using $A^Tk$?

Well, the main thing I am confused about is (1.) and (2.),
 (3.) is maybe just a formality I guess.

**Edit:** Here comes the definitions of matrix transpose and scalar multiplication provided by the book.

Transpose: "We define the transpose of a matrix as:
      $A=(a_ij)$ implies $A^T = (a_ji)$ [The subscript ij changes to ji]"

Scalar multiplication he define by showing matrices which I don't know how to do on a computer, but basically he states that multiplying a matrix $A$ with a scalar $k$ is written as $kA$ and corresponds to multiplying each entry of $A$ by $k$.

Comment: The book's answer is not very well written. (In fact, if a student writes it like that in a linear algebra class that I teach, I would probably give only very little partial credit for that answer. That is to say, the answer is more wrong than right.)

Comment: Since the question the book asks is a "prove" question, you should probably edit your question to include the definitions that your book uses. In particular, what is the definition for transposition and what is the definition for scalar multiplication?

Comment: @WillieWong Ok that doesn't sond very good. I use the book "linear algebra step by step" written by Kuldeep Singh. Do you know any good linear algebra books with correct definitions and proofs?

Comment: The definitions are not a problem. And using the definitions you gave, the answer below is perfectly fine. There are a few questions about book recommendations in linear algebra on this site. You can take a look at them http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[linear-algebra]+recommendation

Answer (score 7):

I agree, this is somewhat an abuse of notation; if we define $k$ as a $1\times 1$ matrix then we do indeed run into problems if we try to use the usual definition of matrix multiplication. And again, unless we define scalar multiplication with a matrix separately to matrix multiplication we do not have that the operation commutes in general (i.e. we would have $[k,\mathbf{A}]\neq 0$ in general).

I would argue that a better way to prove the result would be something like the following:

$$(k\mathbf{A})^{T}_{ij}=(k\mathbf{A})_{ji}=k\mathbf{A}_{ji}$$

Thus we have that:

$$(k\mathbf{A})^{T}=k\mathbf{A}^{T}$$

As required.

Comment: Ok, yes that was a much better proof. Thanks!